# Change umask for www-data(nginx)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx, permissions

I have a website built with nginx. I can't change the umask for the www-data user. I wanted files that were created as www-data user to have rw-rw-r permissions.

I saw a similar problem and a solution for it in Google search, but I don't have a file in the path /etc/init/php-fpm.conf and I have nothing to edit. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: "php-fpm.conf" is usually under `/etc/php`, the question seems to belong to https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: You want to do the wrong thing and ask how to do it. Instead, you should set up [proper permissions model](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be) for PHP-FPM/NGINX